# Serving S3 bucket website from my domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cname

I have a working s3 based static site in the form of:

http://.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

I also already own a totally separate (non-AWS) domain www..com, what I am trying to do is setup a CNAME record so that http://..com to work.

I've tried a number of CNAME records such as:

```
HOST-Record: <mybucket>
Points To: s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

-or-

HOST-Record: <mybucket>
Points To: <mybucket>.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

What I see is that I get an AWS error saying no such bucket - BucketName: ..

I can't figure out the right syntax for doing this right (and given the TTL trial and error is hard).  Any tips?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: This only works when the bucket name matches the hostname exactly.  You need to use CloudFront in front of S3 if you want SSL or a web site served out of a bucket with a different name.